# Print styles not applied in production with webpack / react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, printing

I am running a stack with rails, react on rails, and webpack.
I am able to use print styles successfully in development, however when deploying to production it seems that none of the print styles apply.

In Development
[image: Proper Printing view]

In Production.
[image: Production printing view]

Only appears on production.

Possibly move towards PDF similar to other pages.

Style exists in production, not being applied properly?

In production it is able to find the media print styles.
[image: Printing styles applied from assets folder]

Style in production
@media print{.App-module__d-print-active-pdf___2FlpM{background-color:#fff;height:100%;width:100%;position:fixed;top:0;left:0;margin:0;padding:15px;font-size:14px;line-height:18px}}

In Production.
[image]

UPDATE:

Print styles are applied properly from the assets folder.

[image: Print styles applied from assets folder]

However they are not applied from the applications bundle.
[image: Not applied from applications bundle]

Answer (score 1):

If using [webpacker](https://github.com/rails/webpacker), be sure to set the `media` type on your style tags:

So instead of:

```
<%= stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag 'styles-bundle' %>
```

You would want

```
<%= stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag 'styles-bundle', media: 'all' %>
```

If you'd like more info, the source for this can be helpful:

- [webpacker docs on `stylesheet_packs_with_chunks_tag`](https://github.com/rails/webpacker/blob/7a241e75bd5376524348466aa2daa11661c49f41/lib/webpacker/helper.rb#L125-L129)
- [Rails asset tag helper docs](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper.html#method-i-stylesheet_link_tag)